# Resize bitmap images on the fly inside SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, adapter

Is it possible to resize/reduce size of photos on the fly inside SimpleCursorAdapter?
Scenario is that im getting the path of the photos that are saved on sdcard via a cursor, and showing them in a listview via SimpleCursorAdapter.

here is part of my code in my Activity's onCreate():

```
Cursor c = mydb.rawQuery("select * from events;", null);
if (c != null ) {
            c.moveToFirst();
}
       String[] from = new String[]{DbHandler.column_id, DbHandler.column_name, DbHandler.column_location, DbHandler.column_date, DbHandler.img_loc};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4, R.id.photoInDb};
        SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCurs = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listviewfinal, c, from, to);
        listView.setAdapter(simpleCurs);
```

If its possible, please tell me how? also do i need to define setViewValue?

Comment: :) Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) on how to compress images. And yes, you need to do this in the ViewBinder in setViewValue()

Comment: actually there are two ways: firsrt to use ViewBinder and the second to extend SimpleCursorAdapter and override setImageView()

Comment: hey thanks. i've read that and it didnt work. here is the code i wrote but didnt work. http://pastebin.com/C0uxZqiA - please tell me what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: in setViewValue, first of all: log two things: i and cursor.getString(i) and you will see what you need to change

Comment: amm, what do you mean by logging i?

Comment: i think my problem has a simple solution. i just cant get it to work. please tell write me the afew lines i should put in ViewBinder to make the photos resize and loaded into ImageView!

Comment: how can do anything on android platform without logging?  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: im still in learning phase, so i use the DDMS a lot to get the logs. anyway, i wrote my code as this -> http://pastebin.com/16eeLqs4 but still getting out of memory error. so means the BitmapFactory part is not working. what am i doing wrong here?!!

Comment: much better but why this inJustDecodeBounds
= true ;

Comment: great; so i'm getting somewhere. document said this option will prevent memory allocation! i shouldn't set this parameter?

Comment: i commented out the inJustDecodeBounds and still out of memory! any ideas please?

Comment: log width and height of returned Bitmap

Comment: i tried this but i got NullPointException error.                             Log.d("orange", bm.getHeight()+""); and Log.d("orange", bm.getWidth()+""); after Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getColumnName(4), options);

Comment: im decodeFile change cursor.getColumnName
(4) => cursor.getString(i)

Comment: didnt help. still crashes with errors like Out of memory on a 51121168-byte allocation.